# micro-mu in Kurier font shows up as tcedilla

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

I changed the font of my document to Kurier. Works fine, including the math-option.
Only problem seems to be the upright mu. \micro seems to be mapped to the wrong character?
I included a MWE below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}% 

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%set input encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[math]{kurier}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \section{How to conjure an upright ``mu'' in kurier?}
    Mu in math? $A_{405}=\dfrac{v^6}{4\mu+7\sqrt{x-5}}$ 
        \hspace{1cm}    
    Mu as in \textit{micro}? \SI{823}{\micro\litre}
\end{document}
```

[image: on my machine, the upright(micro) mu turns up as a t with a cédilla-accent?]

Any hints would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

[image: Result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you want to use all `\mu` to be upright? Or if you want to change this instance, you can use `\upmu` from the `upgreek` package. // I am also confused with the question in your title. I compiled and I can see `\micro` works correct.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! upgreek and \upmu work fine. I was really just looking at the \micro-mu for units. If it works with you there's probably something wrong with my installation. I had ruled that out after I got the same effect both on my local installation (I installed the kurier package earlier this week) and on Overleaf.
Maybe I could try to reinstall or find an earlier version?

Comment: Also, the \micro you compiled seemed to be in a serif font? Kurier has a nice sans serif mu, as can be found in https://mirror.lyrahosting.com/CTAN/fonts/kurier/doc/fonts/kurier/kurier-info.pdf (p.9)

Comment: You ask, "\micro seems to be mapped to the wrong character?" Absolutely not. It's an international typographical convention -- observed, unsurprisingly, by the `siunitx` package -- to use an upright (and, if possible, serif) version of the `mu` glyph for the *unit prefix "micro". I suppose this convention is in place precisely to avoid any confusion should a document also contain "mu" as a variable in mathematics.

Answer (score 4):

If you want an upright mu for `\micro`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[math]{kurier}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIPrefix{\micro}{%
  \text{%
    \fontencoding{TS1}\fontfamily{kurier}\selectfont
    \symbol{"B5}%
  }%
}{-6}

\begin{document}

\section{How to conjure an upright ``mu'' in kurier?}

Mu in math? $A_{405}=4\mu$

Mu as in \textit{micro}? \SI{823}{\micro\litre}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Something for me to add here? Or is this a `textcomp` thing?

Comment: @JosephWright I guess that Kurier is classified in a wrong `textcomp` category.